# Hudson not identifying the java & ant installed on ubuntu machine

Tags: java, ubuntu, hudson

I just installed hudson on my ubuntu machine and in the configuration page i see that hudson did not detect the JDK,Ant & Maven installed on my machine..

Is this common or i should do the configuration manually.

[image]

I tried adding the `/usr/bin/` in the JAVA_HOME variable but it says it is not a directory..

Comment: realized that `/usr/bin` is not the JDK path but `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle` is

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I was thinking that hudson to detect Java and Ant installations on my system and display there..but i was wrong.

So i manually added the path for JAVA_HOME and ANT_HOME

I scheduled builds also and it is working great :)